# JavaFX: Cannot open display problem

Tags: display, javafx

I want to create some GUI for Raspberry Pi 1 B. So I found JavaFX is best for my purpose.  Installed it following this tutorial : [oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPiFX/raspberryfx.html](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPiFX/raspberryfx.html)

Created Basic JavaFX Application-Hello World.
Copied BasicFX.jar to pi and ran using ::

`sudo java -jar BasicFX.jar`
But it showed this error ::  `error: could not find or load main class java`

After searching for solution , I found this : [stackoverflow.com/questions/38359076/how-can-i-get-javafx-working-on-raspberry-pi-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359076/how-can-i-get-javafx-working-on-raspberry-pi-3)
. But Running it again showing this error now ::

```
Cannot open display
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at javafx.scene.Node.reapplyCss(Node.java:8983)
        at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Node.java:8946)
        at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:854)
        at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:919)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$9.invalidated(Scene.java:1119)
        at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
        at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(Scene.java:1072)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:347)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:223)
        at basicfx.BasicFX.start(BasicFX.java:37)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:93)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:52)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.loadFont(PrismFontLoader.java:196)
        at javafx.scene.text.Font.<init>(Font.java:319)
        at javafx.scene.text.Font.getDefault(Font.java:86)
        at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.<clinit>(CssStyleHelper.java:1528)
        ... 19 more
Exception running application basicfx.BasicFX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Raspbian Stretch Lite.
 So,I needed to install X11 Xwindows.

I installed minimal packages, enough to run JavaFX ::

```
sudo apt install xorg  libgtk2.0-0
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.